# Int into Array C++ help please

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to separate an integer into an array. I have been using modulo 10 and then dividing by 10 but I believe that will only work for numbers 6 digits or less I may be wrong but it is not working for me. This is what I have:

```
for(int i=0; i<=8; i++){ 
    intAr[i] = intVal%10;
    intVal /= 10;
}
```

It is not working for me and help would be lovely

Comment: the number I am trying to convert is 103000648

Comment: What is the desired versus the actual output?

Comment: It looks fine, the only issue is that it is in reverse order, you need to have intAr[8-i] instead.

Comment: The phrase `does not work` has many meanings. What do you refer to?

Comment: My desired outcome is for 103000648 to be individual digits in the array. Yet when I do the code above and try and apply arithmetic nothing is right. So I tried just displaying the new said array and it is not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting the numbers to be stored in your array right-to-left, you'll need to reverse the way your store the values:

```
for(int i=0; i < 9; i++)
{ 
    intAr[9 - i - 1] = intVal % 10;
    intVal /= 10;
}
```

This will store your number (103000648) like this

```
|-0-|-1-|-2-|-3-|-4-|-5-|-6-|-7-|-8-|
| 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 4 | 8 |
```

instead of

```
|-0-|-1-|-2-|-3-|-4-|-5-|-6-|-7-|-8-|
| 8 | 4 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem i guess you have is that the number in the array is reversed. So try this:

```
for(i=8;i>=0;i--)
{
    intAr[i] = intVal%10;
    intVal /= 10;
}
```

This will work and have the number stored correctly in the array

Comment: wow I feel stupid. Clearly I needed to go in reverse. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @user3282151: Feel free to accept my answer if it had helped you